# Different applications of NPN and PNP transistors in open collector circuits

Tags: npn, pnp

Dear electronics enthusiasts,

I recently encountered an interesting problem in electronic circuit design, related to the application of NPN and PNP-type transistors in open collector circuits.

My understanding is that in an open-collector circuit, NPN transistors and PNP transistors can be used to provide sinking and sourcing capabilities, respectively. But, in a practical application, can I choose to use one of these types based on my needs, not just based on the direction of current flow? In different application scenarios, will the selection of NPN and PNP transistors bring different advantages?

Comment: Unless you have a specific scenario in mind, you choose the transistor type based on if there is a need to sink or source current. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 2):

The question is bit open, but I can give you some ideas of why it might be advantageous to use NPN or PNP in different scenarios.

In switching applications, we often want to use the transistors in a [common-emitter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_emitter) configuration (with the emitter tied to some fixed DC potential), since [common-collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_collector) setups (also known as emitter-follower") have a subtle caveat, a 0.7V output "deficit". I'll focus on common-emitter applications.

In the simplest of circumstances, where you want to use a low-current digital signal to switch on and off power to some heavier load, you have something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fU33o5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

On the left, any potential at IN significantly above a volt or so will switch on the transistor, and power the load. This is fine if it's OK for the load to be connected "high-side", and requires only a single NPN transistor to sink load current.

However, sometimes the load is required to be on the low-side. Perhaps it's already physically connected to ground, like you'd find in vehicle equipment, and can only be "switched" at its positive supply. For that scenario you would require a PNP transistor to do the switching from the top (sourcing current to the load), which is shown on the right.

We still have to use an NPN device to "process" the digital input signal, because that signal will have some potential with respect to ground, commonly either 0V, +3.3V or +5V. To switch off Q3 in the above-right scenario will require a base potential of +12V, which IN cannot ever be. More on this problem later.

For applications that make use of "open-collector outputs", such as many comparators, I<sup>2</sup>C buses and various industrial sensors, generally the polarity has been chosen for us: NPN. One reason is that in the past it's been easier to fabricate NPN transistors (with good performance) in ICs, than PNP. Another reason will become apparent later on.

In a classic open-collector arrangement, using multiple signals to "pull" a common bus potential low, the bus must be pulled high by a passive load, such as a resistor. Here I have several elements, any one of which is able to light the LED, because each has an NPN open-collector (or N-channel MOSFET open-drain) output able to *sink* current from the load:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fofCJH.png)</sup>

The comparators form a "window comparator". In this case their output transistors (NPN, inside the IC) pull their outputs to ground when \$V_{IN2}\$ falls *outside* the range +4V to +8V. We are able to tie their outputs together because they are open-collectors, and may share a common load, like the LED and resistor here. Either comparator may therefore pull that common bus low, and light the LED.

Nothing's stopping you from using PNP transistors (or P-channel MOSFETs) to pull a common bus high:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqcD6h.png)</sup>

This requires care though; notice that with a +5V supply, connected directly to the emitters/sources of the transistors, to switch those transistors *off* requires +5V at their bases/gates. This arrangement won't work with +3.3V digital signals, unless you also use a +3.3V supply.

This issue doesn't arise with NPN open-collector setups from before; since all signals are ground-referenced, any significantly positive input signal, be it +3.3V or +5V will switch on the transistors, and 0V will always switch them off. Another reason why NPN open-collector arrangements are more popular.

There are applications which mandate the use of a certain polarity of transistor. Take this popular current limiting designm, for example, in the blue box:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZWckE.png)</sup>

Current is limited to 1A from the 12V source, but the load could be many devices, a couple of Arduino's, some LEDs, and there may be elements powered from sources other than the 12V shown here. They must all share a common ground in order to be able to communicate with each other.

In such a scenario, it makes sense to throttle current high-side, so that the negative side, ground, can be shared by multiple systems. You don't *have* to do it that way, but nobody likes working with systems whose ground can wobble about, while the positive supply potential remains fixed. You don't have much choice but to use PNP devices here.

While all this isn't strictly related to open collectors, let me finish with a dual ±12V, current limited supply:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fk2KFG.png)</sup>

Again, to be able to have that ground common to both supplies, throttling must be performed on the non-ground side, and for the negative supply, this design requires the use of NPN transistors.